# Issues while merging the videos using AVMutableComposition

Tags: objective-c

I have been working on merging of  videos into a single video using the AVMutableComposition and have got the required output.But i'm getting two different types of issues while merging the videos.

1) I couldn't set the custom frames for the videos using the AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.

2) While playing the merged video, the first merged video is been vanished(removed) after its been stopped. But the other videos are staying correctly after stopped in their respective location.

Please suggestion any solution..

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to change frame for merged video, you should set `AVMutableVideoComposition` render size

2) if you play first and the second video at the same time, the duration of the merged video will be the biggest duration from both videos, in that case you should handle the difference,place a kind of placeholder at the end of first video(can be last frame of the video)